# Angular Material Dialog afterClosed()

Tags: angular, promise, return, angular-material

I want to use an Angular Material Dialog to create a yes/no function that returns true or false depending on whether yes or no was pressed. In the yes/no dialog I have these buttons:

```
<button [mat-dialog-close]="true">Yes</button>
<button [mat-dialog-close]="false">No</button>
```

In my `dialogservice` I call this yes/no dialog by doing this:

```
Yes_No_Prompt(pMessageLines: string[]) {
    const yesNoDialog = this.matdialog.open(DlgYesNoComponent, {
        data: {
            MessageLines: pMessageLines
        }
    });

    yesNoDialog.afterClosed().subscribe(
        (result: boolean) => {
            return result;
        }
    );
}
```

But how do I make this function wait for the line `return result`? Because I now want to use this function by doing something like this:

```
if (this.dialogservice.Yes_No_Prompt()) {
    // something is true (pressed yes)
} else {
    // something if false (pressed no)
}
```

I need to wait for the `return result` line but I don't know how. A promise maybe?

Comment: P.S. Consider using `camelCase` instead of underscores when naming functions.

Comment: @Edric Would you mind explaining why Edric? I feel like you can use any convention you want. Our team uses camel for variables, underscores for functions, and dashes for css...does it really matter?

Comment: IMO, I'm pretty used to using `camelCase` for functions, but that's just my opinion. I agree with you that any coding convention can be used.

Comment: @Edric Ok then all good man. I guess it doesn't really matter at all honestly. As long as the team decides on conventions to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are already using an `Observable` when you do `subscribe`. Just return the Observable from your `Yes_No_Prompt` like this:

```
Yes_No_Prompt(pMessageLines: string[]): Observable<boolean> {
  const yesNoDialog = this.matdialog.open(DlgYesNoComponent, {
    data: {
        MessageLines: pMessageLines
    }
  });

  return yesNoDialog.afterClosed();
}
```

and then

```
this.dialogservice.Yes_No_Prompt().subscribe(result => {
   if(result) {
     // something is true (pressed yes)
   } else {
     // something if false (pressed no)
   } 
});
```

Comment: You don't actually need an equality check here since the `if` statement should execute the first code segment if the result is a truthy value anyways.

Comment: Wasn't sure what the MatDialog can and cannot return, but I believe you and edited my post.

Comment: @GiacomoVoß Thank you for your answer! This is prefect :)

Comment: Once you actively try not to subscribe to an observable until you absolutely have to then you really will start to appreciate the benefits of chaining :-)